# How to store & retrieve an object as a value in option of select element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to store & retrieve an object as a value for option of select element?

```
<select>
  <option value = "{}" selected>lorem</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please share some code snippets that you tried so far?

Comment: If this is purely a JS question (and you're not planning to process the result on the server-side, use jQuery's `data()` functionality instead.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a great pattern to use. You should have the select use some `UUID` (or a unique `ID` field from you object) as the value for your select, and use the `name` or `description` to display to the user.

Then on form submission, you can use `Array.find()` to get the object that was selected.

Answer (score 0):

agree with KiaiFighter. create an array of objects. and populate/create your options from it. then use the filter function to retrieve the selected object. run the snippet below for an example

```js
const myarray = [
  {value: 'one', text: 'one', otherstuff: 'A'},
  {value: 'two', text: 'two', otherstuff: 'B'},
  {value: 'three', text: 'three', otherstuff: 'C'},
  {value: 'four', text: 'four', otherstuff: 'D'},
]

const options = myarray.map(x => `<option value="${x.value}">${x.text}</option>`);
$('#myselect').append(options);

// find elements
$('#mybutton').click(()=> console.log(myarray.filter(x => x.value == $('#myselect').val())[0]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id = "myselect">
 </select>

<button id="mybutton">
submit
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

To store object in option value:

```
var objVar = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({}))));

$('#optionId').append(`<option value = "`+objVar+`">OPTION DATA</option>`);
```

To retrieve object from selected option value:

```
var retrieveData = JSON.parse(atob($('#optionId').val()))
```